# How to delete records based on multiple conditons i sql

Tags: sql

I need to delete records based on the following condition

```
if(A=B & C=D) delete record
if(A=E & C=D or C=F) delete record
```

How can I implement the code in sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want something like this:

```
delete t
    where (A = B and C = D) or
          (A = E and C IN (D, F))
```